# Difficulty v. difficulties

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, nouns

Which form of "difficulty" should I opt for in the following sentence:

> They have immense difficulties easily accessing the texts.

or

> They have immense difficulty easily accessing the texts.

I am inclined to say "difficulty," but I am editing someone else's work and they had originally put "difficulties." Am I wrong, or is he?

Comment: Well, did "they" have only one difficulty, or more than one? On the other hand, I prefer "It was difficult for them to easily access the texts."

Comment: Probably multiple difficulties... which is why I pose the question.

Comment: For multiple difficulties, both forms are correct. It is a matter of preference.

Comment: Also, the word "easily" could be seen as redundant here.

Comment: Combining *immense* and *easily* in one sentence like this is awkard - if I have immense difficulties *easily* accessing the texts, does that imply I have medium difficulties accessing the texts *in a semi-convoluted manner*? What about accessing the texts *the hard way* - do I have no difficulties then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both forms are correct; the *difficulties* form is a bit more specific.  *“They had immense difficulties”* evokes explicit obstacles they encountered.  *“They had immense difficulty”* connotes just that they found the task very difficult.

Good: *Most immigrants have great difficulty finding healthcare.*

More specific: *Most immigrants have great difficulties finding healthcare.*  (There are many things which cause them difficulty.

Questionable: **Most immigrants have great difficulties reading government documents.*  (Unless something else is explicitly under discussion, one would expect that there’s just one main difficulty involved here: language.)

Answer (score 2):

A problem with this sentence is that the noun *difficulties*, which already takes the adjective *immense*, makes the adverb *easily* redundant.

It would be better to either say that it was immensely difficult or that it was not easy. Some options may be these:

*They were unable to access the texts easily.*

*They found it immensely difficult to access the texts.*

*They had immense difficulties accessing the texts.*